# Refresh MFC interface VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I developed an MFC application via Visual Studio 2010. The interface of application contain a tree, I used CPropTree library for building tree. Now I need to refresh this interface periodically and rebuild the tree.

How I do it? Have you any idea?

Comment: I tried to refresh the interface via OnTimer and SetTimer functions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different thread, put `Sleep` or some other instruction. After each iteration, use `SendMessage` (or `PostMessage`) to this tree control, or to the parent of this control. Timers on the same thread won't work properly.